# How to migrate an UIManagedDocument from iCloud enabled to Local Only in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud, uimanageddocument

I am targeting **iOS7** and I use **iCloud** with **UIManagedDocument**.

I want to migrate an `UIManagedDocument` from iCloud enabled to Local Only. When the document is migrated I don't want any ubiquitous content related to it in the Cloud, I want it to be 100% local.

The opposite case, to transform a Local Only `UIManagedDocument` in an iCloud enabled `UIManagedDocument` is easy, it is enough to add the two options `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey` and `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey` in the options dictionary and to migrate the persistent store using `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:`.

I thought that to migrate back from iCloud to Local Only it was enough to migrate the persistentStore passing nil as the options dictionary but this doesn't work:

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = self.managedDocument.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;
NSPersistentStore *ps = [psc.persistentStores objectAtIndex:0];

if(ps){

  NSError *error;
  [psc migratePersistentStore: ps
                        toURL: dbLocalOnlyURL
                      options: nil
                    withType: ps.type
                      error: &error];

  if(error){
    NSLog(@"Error migrating the DB to Local Only: %@", error);
  }else{
    NSLog(@"DB Migrated successfully to Local Only");
  }

 }
```

I get a Cocoa Error 256: The operation couldn't be completed. NSUnderlyingException=unable to open database file, NSSQLiteErrorDomain= 14.

When I try to perform the operation the Using local storage is still 1. But I also tried to this with the Using local storage: 0.

I thought it could be 'because I was trying to migrate the persistent store with the documentState=UIDocumentStateNormal, so I modified the code like this:

```
 [self.managedDocument closeWithCompletionHandler: ^(BOOL success){

    if(success){
      NSLog(@"Document closed succesfully. Performing the migration.");

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = self.managedDocument.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;
        NSPersistentStore *ps = [psc.persistentStores objectAtIndex:0];

        if(ps){

          NSError *error;
          [psc migratePersistentStore: ps
                                toURL: dbLocalOnlyURL
                              options: nil
                             withType: ps.type
                                error: &error];

        if(error){
          NSLog(@"Error migrating the DB to Local Only: %@", error);
        }else{
          NSLog(@"DB Migrated successfully to Local Only");
        }
      }
    }else{
       NSLog(@"Error closing the document.");
    }

  }];
```

but I still get the error. Any hint?

Is it always preferable to close the document before migrating it?

***Note 1***: the migration works without errors if I migrate the persistent store to **another** url but what I want is the very same UIManagedDocument to migrate from iCloud to Local Only.

**Note 2**: I posted this question also on the Apple Developers Forum.

Comment: Sorry, been away for the weekend - see my answer below for a link to a detailed explanation and a video demonstrating the app working an showing the various local and ubiquity containers while things get migrated to and from iCloud. Email me directly if you have any questions.

Comment: many thanks pal. guess you've been in the same boat just before me ;) btw, I don't have your email, please write to me so I can have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [link explaining UIManagedDocument and iCloud Integration and providing details of the classes and methods involved in doing this](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/)

Also take a look at [this video showing how the app works when creating UIManagedDocuments and moving them to and from iCloud](http://youtu.be/r9zqxOjAYPo) to confirm its what you are trying to achieve.